# how to create a table and also all the elements and info in it in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

```
let stock = {
    1001: {product: 'biscuits', cost: 10, quantity: 0},
    1002: {product: 'chocolates', cost: 10, quantity: 0},
    1003: {product: 'ear buds', cost: 1, quantity: 0},
    1004: {product: 'milk packets', cost: 25, quantity: 0},
    1005: {product: 'curd', cost: 25, quantity: 0},
}

function viewStock(){
    document.body.remove();
    var table = document.createElement("table");
    var headerRow = table.insertRow();
    var headerCell1 = headerRow.insertCell(0);
    headerCell1.innerHTML = "New Box";
}
```

Even after giving all this i'm not able to create a table and the matter in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the following should be what you want:

```js
let stock = {
  1001: {
    product: 'biscuits',
    cost: 10,
    quantity: 0
  },
  1002: {
    product: 'chocolates',
    cost: 10,
    quantity: 0
  },
  1003: {
    product: 'ear buds',
    cost: 1,
    quantity: 0
  },
  1004: {
    product: 'milk packets',
    cost: 25,
    quantity: 0
  },
  1005: {
    product: 'curd',
    cost: 25,
    quantity: 0
  },
}

function createTable() {
  var container = document.getElementById("tableContainer");
  var table = document.createElement("table");
  var headerRow = table.insertRow();
  var cell = headerRow.insertCell(headerRow.cells.length);

  container.innerHTML = "";
  cell.textContent = "Product";

  cell = headerRow.insertCell(headerRow.cells.length);
  cell.textContent = "Cost";
  headerRow.appendChild(cell);

  cell = headerRow.insertCell(headerRow.cells.length);
  cell.textContent = "Quantity";
  headerRow.appendChild(cell);

  container.appendChild(table);

  Object.keys(stock).forEach((key) => {


    var row = table.insertRow();
    var cell = row.insertCell(row.cells.length);
    cell.textContent = stock[key].product;
    cell = row.insertCell(row.cells.length);
    cell.textContent = stock[key].cost;
    
    cell = row.insertCell(row.cells.length);
    cell.textContent = stock[key].quantity;
    

  });
}
```

```html
<div id="tableContainer">
</div>
<button onclick="createTable()">Go</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not be calling `document.body.remove()` since this removes the `<body>` tag. Instead, use something like `document.getElementById('foo').append( table )` to append the table to a given DOM element.

In any case, you need to loop through all the elements in your object, construct a row for each of them, and append three cells to the row.

```js
let stock = {
 1001: {product: 'biscuits', cost: 10, quantity: 0},
 1002: {product: 'chocolates', cost: 10, quantity: 0},
 1003: {product: 'ear buds', cost: 1, quantity: 0},
 1004: {product: 'milk packets', cost: 25, quantity: 0},
 1005: {product: 'curd', cost: 25, quantity: 0},
}

function viewStock(){
 var table = document.createElement("table");
 Object.values(stock).forEach( function(rowData) {
 var headerRow = table.insertRow();
 var headerCell1 = headerRow.insertCell(0);
 headerCell1.innerHTML = rowData.product; // For example

 var headerCell2 = headerRow.insertCell(1);
 headerCell2.innerHTML = rowData.cost;

 var headerCell3 = headerRow.insertCell(2);
 headerCell3.innerHTML = rowData.quantity;
    });

    document.getElementById('foo').append( table );
}

viewStock();
```

```html
<div id="foo"></div>
```